# How to get the value of div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the 899 using jQuery?

```
<div class="effectice-price prod_price">
  <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true" id="prod_price"></i>
  899
</div>
```

I have tried this :

```
alert(jQuery(".prod_price").next().text());
```

But not getting any value.

Comment: `jQuery(".prod_price").text()`, no need for the `next()`

Comment: Lol thanks, that's an silly mistake

Comment: use alert($(".prod_price").text());

Comment: do you know 
`<td id="pack_base_price"><i class="fa fa-dollar" aria-hidden="true" ></i> 855</td>`
how to change text of `td` with maintaining the  icon 
i have tried `jQuery("#pack_base_price").text(base_price);` this but its change value with icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `jQuery(".prod_price").text()` directly, no need for the `next()`, And it will be better to use the `trim()` method to remove the extra spaces from the returned string.

```js
console.log(jQuery(".prod_price").text().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="effectice-price prod_price">
  <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true" id="prod_price"></i> 899
</div>
```

Comment: do you know 
`<td id="pack_base_price"><i class="fa fa-dollar" aria-hidden="true" ></i> 855</td>`
how to change text of `td` with maintaining the  icon 
i have tried `jQuery("#pack_base_price").text(base_price);` this but its change value with icon.

Comment: The best solution is to wrap your text "899" by tags `span` for example, that will make the edit simple, do you have any control over the HTML structure?

Answer (score 2):

you should only use

```
$('.prod_price').text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `$(".prod_price").text()` since you are trying to get text of `.prod_price`. `alert(jQuery(".prod_price").next().text());` will not get any value because there is no element next to `.prod_price`

```js
console.log($(".prod_price").text().trim());

$('.prod_price').contents()
            .filter(function() { return this.nodeType != 1 && $.trim($(this).text()) != '' })
            .replaceWith('new text or html');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="effectice-price prod_price">
  <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true" id="prod_price"></i>
899
</div>
```

Comment: do you know `<td id="pack_base_price"><i class="fa fa-dollar" aria-hidden="true" ></i> 855</td>` how to change text of `td` with maintaining the icon i have tried `jQuery("#pack_base_price").text(base_price);` this but its change value with icon

Comment: @krishna check my answer I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(".prod_price").text();
//899 is text of the prod_price
```

Comment: do you know 
`<td id="pack_base_price"><i class="fa fa-dollar" aria-hidden="true" ></i> 855</td>`
how to change text of `td` with maintaining the  icon 
i have tried `jQuery("#pack_base_price").text(base_price);` this but its change value with icon.